# How do I limit my Hotspot's Maximum Speed on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, networking, hotspot

I want to handicap my hotspot speed to disincentivize people from streaming videos from my hotspot. I don't want to block the sites per se, so firewall is a no go. I just need to limit their maximum speed.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting hotspot speed is not a function of Windows 11 hotspot (or 10 or earlier).

You need a hotspot that includes that kind of functionality. Most ordinary hotspots do not.

See if there is a limit on how many people can connect. I am not certain about that.

See if you can determine offenders, change the password and do not let offenders in.  This is probably the best approach for an ad hoc hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have such an option. You might have more luck with
third-party applications.

Here are some that you could try. I don't know how well they work with
a hotspot, so you might need to try and see.

- [NetStalker](https://github.com/hmz777/NetStalker)
  (open source)
- [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/)
  (commercial)
- [NetBalancer](https://netbalancer.com/)
  (commercial)